# The impact of allowing the reward to be negative in a contextual bandit problem

Tags: reinforcement-learning, multiarmed-bandit, contextual-bandit

It seems the contextual bandits problems, as shown in these two papers [Tong Mu, Yash Chandak, Tatsunori Hashimoto, Emma Brunskill: *Factored DRO: Factored Distributionally Robust Policies for Contextual Bandits*](https://openreview.net/forum?id=k6WzeLZjxuP), and [Nian Si, Fan Zhang, Zhengyuan Zhou, Jose Blanchet: *Distributionally Robust Batch Contextual Bandits*](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.05630), generally assumes the reward $R$ are bounded $0<R<M$. I am wondering what would be impacted if $R$ is allowed to be negative.